# W3WP#N Mapping To _LMW3SVC_#_ROOT (Perfmon Counters)

Tags: iis, perfmon

We do have multiple sites hosted on same server with multiple appdomain. I am trying to read perfmon for specific site "Request/Sec" (Any many other). What I encountered is name of instance is not user friendly in Perfmon Monitor. Is there any mapping between W3WP to LM_W3SVC_#_ROOT (Please see screenshot for more details). I tried appcmd, looked into several blogs but no luck. So was wondering if someone knows more about it than it would be really helpful.[image: Multiple W3WP and _LM_W3SVC]

Update:

Does it come from C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config? If yes is there any way to give it better name in perfmon monitor? If no than still my original question exist :)

Answer (score 11):

In _LM_W3SVC_**N**_ROOT, the N is the site id in IIS. You can easily find this by opening IIS Manager (Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager). Expand the computer and then sites. To the right of each site, you'll see an ID value.

For w3wp#**N**, it's a bit harder to track this down. The first w3wp instance to run is called "w3wp". Every other instance will be "w3wp#N". The N in this case **IS NOT** the N from above. It is simply a sequential number. There is a counter called *\Process\ID Process*. That will identify the process id of the "w3wp#N"instance you're looking at.

You'll then need to either:

- run: c:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd list wp
- Open IIS Manager, click on the computer name, on the left, and open "Worker Processes"

Both methods will list out the IIS site and it's associated w3wp.exe process ID.

Comment: Clarification on how to get the w3wp#N / Application Pool correspondence in Perfmon: 1) Add Counters 2) Process 3) Select all w3wp instances 4) Add>> 5) OK 6) All of the w3wp instance will be listed on the bottom 7) Click on each line and observe Last/Average/Minimum/Maximum - that's your Process ID. Very strange way, but that's the only way I was able to get that number.